# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;Reference is not allowed in prolog. auto generated XHTML, java

Tags: java, xhtml, xml-parsing, saxparser, libreoffice

I just wanted to try out [Flying Saucer](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html) to generate a PDF from an xhtml code. So what I did was to make a layout in LibreOffice, let it generate the xhtml code and (wanted to) hand this over to the parsing library (in java) to generate the pdf. 
However, I couldn't take over all of the xml-code 1:1 as i needed to escape things.. so i escaped all "<" with "<" and all ">" with ">" and all double-quotes with a " \" ".

When trying to parse the whole thing i get following error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:2: Reference is not allowed in prolog.
```

I tried to track it down via some logic thinking and googling. If I understood right following is my "prolog":

```
    buf.append("&lt;?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?&gt;");
    buf.append("&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/xhtml-math11-f.dtd\"&gt;");
    buf.append("&lt;html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"&gt;&lt;!--This file was converted to xhtml by OpenOffice.org - see http://xml.openoffice.org/odf2xhtml for more info.--&gt;&lt;head profile=\"http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/\"&gt;&lt;meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8\"/&gt;&lt;title xml:lang=\"en-US\"&gt;- no title specified&lt;/title&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.title\" content=\"\" xml:lang=\"en-US\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.language\" content=\"en-US\" scheme=\"DCTERMS.RFC4646\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.source\" content=\"http://xml.openoffice.org/odf2xhtml\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.issued\" content=\"2012-11-20T20:59:05.11\" scheme=\"DCTERMS.W3CDTF\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.provenance\" content=\"\" xml:lang=\"en-US\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.subject\" content=\",\" xml:lang=\"en-US\"/&gt;&lt;link rel=\"schema.DC\" href=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" hreflang=\"en\"/&gt;&lt;link rel=\"schema.DCTERMS\" href=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" hreflang=\"en\"/&gt;&lt;link rel=\"schema.DCTYPE\" href=\"http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/\" hreflang=\"en\"/&gt;&lt;link rel=\"schema.DCAM\" href=\"http://purl.org/dc/dcam/\" hreflang=\"en\"/&gt;&lt;style type=\"text/css\"&gt;");
```

sorry for the huge (and ugly) thing, but well.. next thing i did, was commenting out line per line to see where the wrong thing is.

the error still appears if i comment out the first two lines of this, after the third i get a different error ("Content is not allowed in prolog" or similiar)

however, here is the third line.. i can't find the error, every help is appreciated :)

```
        buf.append("&lt;html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"&gt;&lt;!--This file was converted to xhtml by OpenOffice.org - see http://xml.openoffice.org/odf2xhtml for more info.--&gt;&lt;head profile=\"http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/\"&gt;&lt;meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8\"/&gt;&lt;title xml:lang=\"en-US\"&gt;- no title specified&lt;/title&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.title\" content=\"\" xml:lang=\"en-US\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.language\" content=\"en-US\" scheme=\"DCTERMS.RFC4646\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.source\" content=\"http://xml.openoffice.org/odf2xhtml\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.issued\" content=\"2012-11-20T20:59:05.11\" scheme=\"DCTERMS.W3CDTF\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.provenance\" content=\"\" xml:lang=\"en-US\"/&gt;&lt;meta name=\"DCTERMS.subject\" content=\",\" xml:lang=\"en-US\"/&gt;&lt;link rel=\"schema.DC\" href=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" hreflang=\"en\"/&gt;&lt;link rel=\"schema.DCTERMS\" href=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" hreflang=\"en\"/&gt;&lt;link rel=\"schema.DCTYPE\" href=\"http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/\" hreflang=\"en\"/&gt;&lt;link rel=\"schema.DCAM\" href=\"http://purl.org/dc/dcam/\" hreflang=\"en\"/&gt;&lt;style type=\"text/css\"&gt;");
```

thanks in advance!

edit1: http://validator.w3.org/check validated it as totally correct!

Comment: You are escaping things you shouldn't be.  If it's valid xml, all the things that need to be escaped already are, and you don't need to do any of that.

Comment: but i have to escape things, because otherwise i can't use them in java code as strings...
[this guy's tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html) also escapes things... his code is just much less complex.

Comment: This guy's tutorial is 5 years old, has links that don't work, and I wouldn't trust it a bit.  The reason you're getting an error is that the document should have '<' characters where you're putting "&lt;".

Comment: hmm so if you're right. what would be the way to deal with this characters (which prevent one from "hardcoding" the whole deal.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding?  Just save to a file from LibreOffice and use Java to read it from the file.

Comment: my whole thing is: i need to create a bill dynamically which has a certain layout and certain spaces to put values in.
i think creating a file and reading all the strings (there are pretty many) would be quite sensible to errors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're being confused by the bad layout of [this blog article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html).  If you download the [sample code](http://today.java.net/today/2007/06/26/FlyingSaucerPDFSampleCode.zip), you'll see that the '<' and '>' characters are *not* converted to "&lt;" and "&gt;" in the author's actual code and data.

In order to get quotes into hard-coded Java strings, you do of course have to escape them.  But you shouldn't need any of this xml escaping.

Comment: hmmm i was trusting the author because it seemed to be a "founding contributor" but I get your point and looked at the sample code. I will probably be able to try this this afternoon and accept your answer if it works that way!

Comment: one more thing: in the author's sample code, quotes are converted to single-quotes. So shall I escape them via \" or replace them with a single quote (like in the sample code)